# How does Recycler view draw individual rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As per my understanding, the following things happen on a broad level when data is to be shown using the `RecyclerView`.

1) Recycler view calls the `onCreateViewHolder()` method which returns a ViewHolder object and then calls `onBindViewHolder()` which binds the data with individual views contained in the ViewHolder.

Doubt:
As `RecyclerView` object never gets the total inflated View of the XML file,  It only gets the views wrapped inside the `ViewHolder` object. How is `RecyclerView` able to draw the `ViewHolder` views correctly? Do the individual Views present in the `ViewHolder` have sufficient information about their parent layout, padding, margin, where they should be placed in their parent layout?

Comment: What do you mean by "Recycler view object never gets the total inflated View"?
The RecyclerView.ViewHolder constructor requires a itemView parameter, which is your inflated xml view.

Comment: The inflation is done in the method onCreateViewHolder(). This inflated View of the XML is passed to the ViewHolder constructor to create the ViewHolder object which is then returned by the onCreateViewHolder method to the RecyclerView. Hence the RecyclerView only gets the ViewHolder object and not the total inflated View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point which I missed here is that the custom `ViewHolder` class which we define is an extended version of base class `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class which holds the actual reference to the inflated View. The constructor of this class receives the View object reference which we created by inflating the XML file of the row to be displayed. Hence this View object which represents the entire hierarchy of the row file layout is saved as an instance member which is named as itemView in the android defined base class (`RecylclerViewer.ViewHolder`).

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        /* We are calling the base class constructor passing the Entire View hirerachy */
        super(itemView) 
    }
}
```

When we extend the ViewHolder class, we add additional View members in this class (like TextView, Buttons etc.) which is an optimisation so that while binding the data in `onBindViewHolder()`, we can avoid calls to findViewById on the parent View object.
Thus our custom `ViewHolder` object not only wraps the sub view objects but also holds / wraps the reference to the entire inflated View. Because of this, `RecyclerView` is able to draw the row completely.

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView contains some components.

1. Adapter (Provide data)
2. View Holder (Provide view for binding data)
3. LayoutManager (Locate position of each item)
4. and others.

You could read this article to deep inside RecyclerView. [(Link)](https://android.jlelse.eu/understanding-recyclerview-components-part-2-1fd43001a98f)